# Nix derivation does not include cabal data-files when running Haskell application

Tags: haskell, package-managers, nixos

I have a haskell project that uses `cabal.mkDerivation` to make a Nix derivation.

When I run `nix-build` in the project root I get the expected `result` symlink after the build is successful.

If I enter that directory I have 4 directories:

- bin
- lib
- nix-support
- share

Where my executable exists inside `bin`. When I try to run my executable it cannot find my application files nor the dynamic libraries. I understand that this is due to to missing environment variables that set up all the paths of the package.

**How can I run the executable of my package with the right environment variables without installing it?**

I'm aware that I can use `nix-shell` to use `cabal run` to run the executable, but I want to run the executable in the deployed state.

### Edit #1: More information

Here is my `default.nix` in my project:

```
{ haskellPackages ? (import <nixpkgs> {}).haskellPackages_ghc783_no_profiling }:

let
  inherit (haskellPackages)
    blazeHtml
    ... list of deps
    ;
in
  cabal.mkDerivation (self: {
    pname           = "myproject";
    version         = "0.0.1";
    src             = ./;
    enableSplitObjs = false;

    buildTools = [
      yesodBin
      cabalInstall
    ];

    buildDepends = [
      blazeHtml
      ... list of deps
    ];
})
```

Here is the relevant part of my cabal-file which contains the list of data files used by the application:

```
data-files: config/favicon.ico
          , config/robots.txt
          , config/settings.yml
          , static/css/*.css
          , static/fonts/*.eot
          , static/fonts/*.svg
          , static/fonts/*.ttf
          , static/fonts/*.woff
          , static/img/*.jpg
```

When the application is deployed by using `cabal install` the structure would be:

```
  myproject
▾ config
    favicon.ico
    robots.txt
    settings.yml 
▾ static
    ▸ css
    ▸ fonts
    ▸ img
```

The executable finds all files relatively to the current working directory.

Comment: How does your application normally find it's files? Do you use the _Paths module produced by cabal?

Comment: @bennofs The directories `config` and `static` are in the root of the project. So when I run `cabal run` in the project root the files are looked up relatively. See my edit for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution here is not to fix the nix expression. Instead, you should extend your application such that it uses `getDataFileName` which is provided by the cabal-generated Paths module to find it's files (you could use it as a fallback).

For more information about this see: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.de/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html

Answer (score 2):

Installing it would have the same problem. Wrap your binary with makeWrapper and set the necessary environment variables.

Comment: I just found out that enabling `isExecutable` in `cabal.mkDerivation` fixed this automatically.

Comment: Any idea how to fix lookup of data files used by the application? Right now they exist in `$out/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3/myproject-0.0.1/`. Can't seem to find any examples of other applications in nixpkgs that does this.